# How to change string to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a string variable, how to change it to array:

```
$checkedValues  = $_POST['checkedValues'];

variable $checkedValues = 257, 259, 261

Array ( [0] => 257, 259, 261 )
```

How to change this variable into an array like as

```
 Array ( [0] => 257,[1] => 259,[2] => 261 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `explode()` for this.

```
$checkedValues = "257, 259, 261";
$arr = explode(", ",$checkedValues);
```

Output for this will be,

```
Array
(
    [0] => 257
    [1] => 259
    [2] => 261
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$checkedValues = "257, 259, 261";
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $checkedValues);

print_r($keywords);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 257
    [1] => 259
    [2] => 261
)
```

> ***split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f***

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = $_POST['checkedValues'];
$delimiter = ",";
$to_array = explode("$delimiter", $string);
var_dump($to_array);
```